# Servicio creado en c# muestra "Accesos denegado" en el visor de eventos

Tags: c#, servicio

estoy realizando un servicio de windows en c". El servicio trata de que cada 30 segundos revise si hay un proceso iniciado lo cierre.  Cuando lo pruebo en visual studio funciona de manera correcta, el problema es cuando ya esta instalado en windows, me muestra "Acceso denegado" en el visor de eventos, note que cada que encuentra el proceso ugraf es cuando muestra el error en el visor de eventos. Anexo código.

```
public partial class solidEservice : ServiceBase
{
    bool bandera = false;
    public solidEservice()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        tLapso.Start();
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        tLapso.Stop();
    }

    private void tLapso_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bandera) return;
        try
        {
            bandera = true;
            foreach (Process proceso in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (proceso.ProcessName == "ugraf")
                {
                    proceso.Kill();

                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Proceso detenido, EventLogEntryType.Information", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
        bandera = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: no necesita permisos de administrador?

Comment: Ejecuto como administrador, también agregue al proyecto un archivo app.manifest donde otorgo el permiso de administrador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La elevación de privilegios utilizando app.manifest sólo es útil para programas que se ejecutan cuando hay una sesión de usuario abierta.

Cuando se trata de los servicios de windows, estos se ejecutan sin necesidad de que un usuario inicie sesión.

Para resolverlo, debes configurarle un inicio de sesión al servicio.

- Abre el administrador de servicios (Presiona `Windows+R` para abrir el diálogo `Ejecutar`, escribe `services.msc`, y presionea Enter o selecciona Aceptar).
- Busca tu servicio en la lista, dale click derecho y selecciona propiedades.
- En la pestaña inicio de sesión, selecciona si prefieres que se ejecute como cuenta del sistema local o como una cuenta de usuario.

Más información relacionada con la creación de servicios de windows [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]