# Problemas al convertir cadena numerica en decimal

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un servicio windows con c# y .Net core 3.1.

Basicamente en la maquina de desarrollo no hay problemas al convertir la siguiente cadena a decimal funciona perfectamente:

### En la maquina de desarrollo

```
decimal var1 = Convert.Decimal("-37.7130883")
resultado: --> -37.7130883
```

### Una vez en Produccion

```
decimal var1 = Convert.Decimal("-37.7130883")
resultado: --> -377130883.0
```

Alguien tiene una explicación y ¿como validar? ¿programaticamente existe alguna solución?.

Adjunto imagenes de la configuracion de ambas maquinas... ¿un error de Microsoft?

### Desarrollo

[image: Imagen desarrollo]

[image: Image2 Desarrollo]

### Servidor

[image: Imagen Servidor]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Puedes probar configurando  los puntos decimales y separadores en el panel de control de la maquina en producción, `Panel de Control > Reloj y Región > Region - Configuración Adicional > Personalizar Formato` Ubica las etiquetas **Símbolo de Separación de Miles** y **Símbolo Decimal**, creo que tu programa en producción toma como separador decimal la **,** y al **.** lo ve como miles, ósea tu programa esta viendo el número que te indica por que el . no es decimal si no un simple miles.

Comment: En tu pregunta mencionas que se trata de un servicio y muestras capturas de pantalla de la configuración regional de un usuario en el servidor. Pero te pregunto: ¿Se trata del mismo usuario con el que tienes configurado el inicio de sesión del servicio? [Esta repuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/406488/182188) describe el procedimiento para abrir la configuración del inicio de sesion de un servicio.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema es causado porque la configuración cultural es diferente en las dos computadoras.
Si tu fuente de datos considera el punto como símbolo decimal (tal como el ejemplo en tu pregunta), puedes utilizar la sobrecarga del método [Convert.ToDecimal(...)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) que tiene un parámetro para la cultura.

```
decimal var1 = Convert.ToDecimal("-37.7130883", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

De esta forma siempre producirá el mismo resultado sin importar la cultura que la máquina tenga configurada.